# why does xCode 8.3.3 variable window show very limited data?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Im using xcode 8.3.3 and I've recently started playing around in swift.
Im not sure if its just me but i feel like swifts debugging capabilities are completely broken, but at the same time, no one else seems to be complaining so i can only assume this is something wrong with my configuration.

If you look at the image below, you can see than `calendar` in the variable view doesn't have a property called `title` (or at least it wasn't visible to me at all), but using `po` shows it. You can also see that most objects drill down to nothing (ie; `[0] id` properties, is something supposed to be there?). At the same time, `name` and `name2` is nonexistant in the variable view window. This can be problematic when debugging/inspecting properties for a class.

Ive had this issue since i tried to hop on the swift bandwagon back when 2.3 was the latest version. Because of this, I've ended up reverting back to objective-c every time i need add to my existing app.

[image]